# In Sequelize model.destroy({ truncate: true }) does not reset primary key

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

In Sequelize, I am using this function model.destory({ truncate: true }), it delete all data in table. But the issue is that it does not reset the primary key sequence in table which should be set to Zero. I am using Mysql.
Some said that Mysql automatically reset the primary key sequence, but it is not happening in my case.

Here is my code:

```
db.Booking.destroy({ truncate: { cascade: false } })
    .then(() => {
      res.json({ status: true });
    }, (err) => {
      console.log('truncate: ', err);
      res.json(err);
    });
```

Comment: Related for SQLite: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55966627/how-to-reset-autoincrement-primary-key-with-sequelize

Answer (score 17):

You're not using the correct syntax:

```
db.Booking.destroy({ truncate: { cascade: false } })
```

That should be:

```
db.Booking.destroy({ truncate : true, cascade: false })
```

See [the documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/v3/api/model/#destroyoptions-promiseinteger).

Comment: It does not work for me. I'm not using the set to null approach which is the default

Comment: @Marc might be worthwhile to create a new question for your specific issue.

Comment: Note that this does not work for sqlite3 "5.0.2" on sequelize 6.5.1. `truncate: true` does not change the SQLite querry since it has no `TRUNCATE` only an automatic optimization, so it just runs `DELETE FROM`, which does not reset the index. No one has managed so far without raw SQL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55966627/how-to-reset-autoincrement-primary-key-with-sequelize an issue was created at: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/13286

Answer (score 0):

if you are, in any case, using a custom foreign key, use this instead

```js
db.Booking.truncate({cascade: true, restartIdentity:true})
```

as `destroy` would not work at will with custom foreign key

this one is nested pretty deep in the documentation

[See here](https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/model.js%7Emodel#static-method-truncate)