# How to reset autoIncrement primary key with sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sqlite, sequelize.js

I use sqlite3 as my DB and use `sequelize` library to handle it.
I have a module and want to reset `autoIncrement` primary key after truncating it.

```
    var logModule = db.logModule()
    logModule.destroy({

        where:{},
        truncate: true
    })
```

But I found this way just clear all records in my table, didn't reset the `autoIncrement` primary key to zero.

Is there any way to reset primary key after clear all records in my table?

Comment: The whole point of autoincrement in sqlite is that a rowid never ever gets reused. Leave out the autoincrement when defining an `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` column, or just live with it. What the rowid is shouldn't matter anyways. It's not like you're ever going to get close to the maximum value if you're letting sqlite pick the rowid...

Answer (score 12):

You should pass `restartIdentity: true` to destroy / truncate methods in sequelize.

```
   models[modelName]
     .destroy({ truncate: true, restartIdentity: true })
```

`restartIdentity` - only used in conjunction with TRUNCATE. Automatically restart sequences owned by columns of the truncated table.

This does not work as expected with the id field generated by sequelize for sqlite.

You have to [explicitly invoke the SQL](https://www.designcise.com/web/tutorial/how-to-reset-autoincrement-number-sequence-in-sqlite#:%7E:text=DELETE%20FROM%20%60sqlite_sequence%60%20WHERE%20%60,is%20inserted%20in%20that%20table.):

```
await sequelize.query(`DELETE FROM "sqlite_sequence" WHERE "name" = 'table_name'`)
```

Comment: This does not work as expected with the id field generated by sequelize for sqlite.

You have to [explicitly invoke the SQL](https://www.designcise.com/web/tutorial/how-to-reset-autoincrement-number-sequence-in-sqlite#:~:text=DELETE%20FROM%20%60sqlite_sequence%60%20WHERE%20%60,is%20inserted%20in%20that%20table.):

```
DELETE FROM `sqlite_sequence` WHERE `name` = 'table_name'
```

Comment: [Issue raised](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/13286)

Answer (score 6):

`SQLite` keeps track of the largest `ROWID` that a table has ever held using the special `SQLITE_SEQUENCE` table. The  `SQLITE_SEQUENCE` table is created and initialized automatically whenever a normal table that contains an `AUTOINCREMENT` column is created.

After destroy the table, you have to execute a query to reset `SQE` value for the table

```
sequelize.query("UPDATE SQLITE_SEQUENCE SET SEQ=0 WHERE NAME='log_module_table_name'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this;

```
Object.values(sequelize.models).map(function(model) {
  return model.destroy({ truncate: true });
});
```